# changing memory allocation of a kubernetes worker node

Tags: kubernetes, memory-management, kubelet

**My set up**

I have one physical node K8s cluster where I taint master node so it can also act a worker. the node has Centos7 with total of 512 GB memory. I am limiting my experiments to one node cluster; once a solution is found, I  will test it on my small scale k8s cluster where master and worker services are on separate nodes.

**What I am trying to do**

I want k8s worker to use only 256GB of memory to begin with. later on with if a particular node condition is met I want to increase memory allocation for k8s worker to  (lets say) 400GB

**Where I am right now with this**

1. I reboot my machine and node is up with full 512 GB memory.
2. I use `chmem -d <range>` to offline 256 GB memory.  Now OS only sees 256 GB memory is available.
3. I follow steps from  `kubeadm init`  to `kubectl taint  nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-`
4. My single node K8s set is up and I can deploy upto 2 pods. each pod requests 100Gi and limited to 200Gi memory usage. Pod are executing `sleep 100000`. so there is no memory stress.
5. When I try to launch third pod; pod is stuck in pending state because scheduler detects that the only worker node its managing is out of allocatable memory resource.  This make sense. the third pod is simply stuck in pending state forever.
6. Now after some time; the node met the required condition; at this point I used `chmem -e <range>` to enable some memory and now OS sees 400GB.
7. At this point I want to make k8s worker aware of this memory resource capacity change so the third pod stuck in pending stage can be deployed.
8. This is where I need your help. how can I update memory resource capacity of a worker without restarting my k8s. If I restart the cluster, it can see 400GB memory; but it means I need to kill already running pods and killing already running pod is not acceptable.

Comment: Hello, please tell if you tried what Bernard Halas linked you in the comments i.e.: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a long shot, but you can try to restart kubelet via `systemctl restart kubelet`. The containers should not be restarted this way and there's a hope that once restarted, it'll notice the increased memory configuration.

Comment: I checked kubelet logs; it reflects change in memory capacity as I online/offline memory. but it has no impact on scheduling decision for third pod; it remains in pending stage. On the other side when I check `kubectl describe nodes` details  memory capacity remains unchanged and does not reflect changes due to memory/online/offline.  I also tried restarting kubelet as you suggested but no change in scheduling behavior or pod status

Comment: Hm, in the etcd there's likely the old information about the node memory size and the scheduler uses that when making decisions about scheduling new pods. Not sure yet how to force an update here. On a side-note: pls keep in mind that K8s treats pods as ephemeral and they will get killed over time eventually.

Comment: So unless the change you did takes effect in a few mins, there's another long shot: By modifying one of the memory reservation parameters for `kubelet`, you might be able to force a re-configuration of the node in the database. E.g. change the value for `system-reserved` and observe: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/

Comment: I see that you used `kubeadm` to provision your cluster but have you made any changes to the `kubelet` configuration?

Comment: Thanks Bernard; restarting kubelet worked... everytime i online/offline memory, os memory maps and metrics were updated immediately, but in order for K8s to get these changes- i restarted kubelet and within few seconds it was reflected at K8s level as well. Pods/containers kept running as kubelet was getting restarted; which was a surprise; i was under impression that if i restart kubelet on a running worker; it would kill/restart all the pods.

Answer (score 1):

- Please provide output of below command

```
kubectl describe nodes
```

- Restarting kubelet with below command should work because kubelet recalculates the allocatable cpu and memory every time it starts

```
systemctl restart kubelet
```

- Did you try removing and recreating the third pod after restarting kubelet ?

Comment: Thanks Sagar restarting kubelet worked... everytime i online/offline memory, os memory maps and metrics were updated immediately, but in order for K8s to get these changes- i restarted kubelet and within few seconds it was reflected at K8s level as well.  Pods/containers kept running as kubelet was getting restarted; which was a surprise; i was under impression that if i restart kubelet on a running worker; it would kill/restart all the pods.

Comment: kubelet system daemon calls the Container Runtime APIs to create Containers. So actually it is the container runtime like Docker, Containerd, etc. that is running the containers. So, you can restart kubelet system daemon anytime without fear of containers getting restarted. But if due to some reason, kubelet daemon does not start and it is down for long time, then Kubernetes things that node is down and Kubernetes evicts Pods from the Node which causes Deployment/ReplicaSet to start the pods on other nodes. In this case, you will have over capacity problem.